# How to upload a transparent video to wordpress

Tags: video, html5-video

We are trying to get an animation we made to work transparent on the background of our website:  http://preview.geomedia.co.uk/lucas-kennedy/

As you can see we have left the old static cloud on the website for you to see how that works.

As we have an interactive element in the background ideally we would like to keep this.

Looking around, we can see that we need this as a .mov file for this to work properly, however when saving this file it comes to over 500mb, which is far to large to upload.

Overall what we are looking for as an end product is just to have the animated cloud moving on the screen with no black background.

I have tried testing other videos online from royalty free site which say they are transparent, but this is not working either.

So is this even possible on a website?

Thanks for looking. :-)

Comment: How is this related to WordPress?

Comment: Because this is going on to a WordPress site.

Comment: This is no WordPress-specific problem, so the tag is wrong.

Comment: It is though as when you upload a .mov file this doesn't seem to working either. I wouldn't of put the tag in if it wasn't useful, there are 3 problems. Are you here to help or prove a point?

Comment: WordPress will not perform any modifications on the encoding of your video file. And if you use a video-tag and your browser is capable of displaying videos with alpha channels this will work. Just tried it locally, works fine, even in WP instances.

Comment: So, no WordPress problem after all and your tag is therefore misleading. Screenshot: https://ibb.co/dfSwUy Top shows the "integrated media player", below is a raw video-element, video is from here: https://simpl.info/videoalpha/video/soccer1.webm

Comment: So I have got to the point where we have this: http://preview.geomedia.co.uk/lucas-kennedy/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/No_outline_transparent.mp4

Comment: I can't show you the transparent video as nothing displays on my screen. but in the above link is the animation we are trying to achieve.

Comment: What is your output format? MP4 does not support video transparency through alpha channels.

Comment: So we have a mov file: http://preview.geomedia.co.uk/lucas-kennedy/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/No_outline_transparent_2_1.mov
As you can see nothing seems to show, but this is the same video as the one above, so I'm a bit lost over the whole thing?

Comment: Seems like the file is broken. Try exporting it to WebM, that should work.

Comment: Hi there, ok no problem I will give this ago and see how I get on, will be back to you!

Comment: Right so: http://preview.geomedia.co.uk/lucas-kennedy/
I have put in the video as you can see on the right if you hover over this. It works when uploaded to wordpress: http://preview.geomedia.co.uk/lucas-kennedy/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/cloud.webm
What is going on here and why isn't it pulling through?